# Windows service to upload to S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, service, upload

I have a windows service that monitors a folder for new files and then sends to a S3 Bucket to process. The service works for the first file, but then I get this exception for any files after that.

***Message: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\PDFs\sample-2.pdf' because it is being used by another process.' when writing an object***

Here is part of the code for the upload:

```
 private static async Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

            //await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName);

            Log.WriteLine("FilePath: " + filePath);

            using (var fileToUpload = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileToUpload, bucketName, fileToUpload.Name);
            }

            Log.WriteLine("File uploaded: " + filePath);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message: '"+ e.Message +"' when writing an object");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on pc. Message: '" + e.Message + "' when writing an object");
        }
    }
```

I originally had the fileMode set to Read and File Access set to Read as well.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you waiting enough time for the sample-2.pdf file to finish writing before you pick it up? Like are the PDFs being uploaded from an FTP, or dumped there by another process? Sometimes the file will take a second or 2 to finish uploading, and during that time it is locked by the OS.

Comment: @Jon Yeah, I've waited minutes to hours. If I restart the service then I can upload a single file again. I am just copying and pasting the file from one dir to the monitored dir.

Comment: Shouldn't this line be fileToUpload = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))   ?

Comment: @Jon That is what I originally had and it doesn't work. Tried again just barely to be sure.

Comment: @Jon It works if I copy multiple files in at the same time. The issue appears to be one at a time.

Comment: @Jon Could it have something to do with it being an async task?

Comment: Is it possible that you have 2 threads trying to access the same file at the same time? Try just uploading the files serially, using one thread, one at a time.

Comment: Ok, so I figured something out. It appears to only have the issue if I copy and paste. If I move the file to the directory it works every time. Is there a way to detect if the file is finished copying before atempting to upload?

Comment: Yes, I use the answer from here IsFileLocked()  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use